# Adding third party Cordova Plugin in IBM Mobile first 7.1 using Eclipse

Tags: mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

I am new to IBM mobile firstplatform. I have installed the MFP 7.1 plugin in Eclipse. Any idea how do I add a third party Cordova plugin in my existing MFP project, using Eclipse?

We can do it using command line. But I need to do it using Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you cannot do this via command line.  Hybrid apps created using mobilefirst do not support 3rd party plug-in installation via the Cordova CLI.

The only way to do this by command line, is by creating actual Cordova applications (unlike classic hybrid apps as you know them from Studio): https://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/08/17/getting-started-with-mobile-development-and-ibm-mobilefirst-7-1/

There is, however, a workaround you can follow for Studio: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2015/08/03/integrating-3rd-party-cordova-plug-ins/
Note however that it is only a workaround and not an official solution.

Comment: Thanks Idan! Will surely look into this!