# Where do I write code to clear cookies in Hybrid iOS App

Tags: ionic-framework, webkit, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a hybrid app which uses Ionic and IBM's Mobilefirst platform. During login we get a cookie from the authentication service. I have to remove this cookie on logout or next time the user can log in even with incorrect credentials.

So during logout I call `WL.Client.reloadApp()` before going back to login screen. This clears the cookies and then login works correctly in Android and browsers. But in iOS cookies aren't cleared on reload and having searched I came across a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471629/how-to-delete-all-cookies-of-uiwebview) to clear cookies using native code.

But my confusion is where do I add this native code? There are a few initialization methods in my application's default .m file. I have tried adding the code to clear cookies in `-(void)wlInitDidCompleteSuccessfully`. But this block doesn't seem to be executed on reloading.

Any suggestion on what I should try to fix this problem.

Comment: What is your MFP version?

Comment: I'm using mfp v7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

1. Use the WL.Client.deleteCookie(name) API to clear the cookie.
2. Write a simple Cordova plugin (https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/adding-native-functionality/) to clear the cookies or google for 'cordova clear cookies' to find such plugins in the market.

Comment: the first solution doesn't work. 
As to the second solution. I'm using Mobilefirst Studio with Eclipse. I have seen one of your [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37023501/adding-third-party-cordova-plugin-in-ibm-mobile-first-7-1-using-eclipse), that to add Cordova plugin I need to use cli only or the workaround mentioned there for Studio plugin.Is this true even if I update to v8.0 of MobileFirst Studio?

Comment: In 7.1 you can create your own custom Cordova plugin and this is documented in the tutorials for 7.1 (answered updated with link). v8.0 is completely different from 7.1 - you do not create Hybrid apps, rather you create Standard Cordova apps, which thus allow you to also use Cordova Plugman to install 3rd party plugins.